# How to fit a multiple regression model that takes into account 50 days of each individual's history

Tags: regression, spss, multiple-regression, forecasting, matrix

I am using simple linear regression to predict the number of days of school a single student might miss after 250 days using their cumulative daily attendance data over the first 50 days of the student's schooling--i.e., predicting how many days of school they will have missed at 250 days based on their individual cumulative 50 day trajectory. This works fairly well for about 75% of students.

As a next step, I want to refine Y = a + bX to test whether I can more accurately predict the number of days a student might miss after 250 days (based on their first 50 days), taking into account their gender, ethnicity, etc., using multiple regression.

I'd understand how to do this if I were using regression to predict an outcome based on a group of single co-ordinates, i.e. predicting a test result based on the number of days missed for 100 males / females. But, I'm not sure how to generate a regression model that takes into account each 50 day matrix of co-ordinates for all 100 student simultaneously. I then want to take the general effects of gender, ethnicity on the slope of this model (i.e., Y = a + b1X1 +b2X2...) and plug it back into the individual student's regression line to test if I can more accurately predict their 250 days outcome.

Could anyone offer me some starting guidance on conducting regression in this situation please? Or indeed even if regression is the appropriate choice? I'm using Oracle Analytics for student linear regression and was planning to use SPSS for multiple regression.

Comment: Welcome to the site, @user27768. Can you clarify what you mean by "50 day matrix of co-ordinates"? It seems to me your initial simple regression model just has the total number of days missed over the 1st 50 as the predictor variable. Ie, Alice missed 5 out of the first 50 days, so for her x=5; Barney missed 7 days, so for him x=7, etc. You can add extra variables (like gender & ethnicity) to this model w/o difficulty.

Comment: Hi Gung, Thanks for editing my question title - that makes more sense.

Comment: Hi @Gung, Yes, that's correct - but it's more the cumulative trajectory i.e. for Alice she misses 2 days after 10 days, 4 days after 25 days 9 days after 40 days creating a regression slope that could use to predict her pattern for the next 200 days. Other students with other characteristics (e.g. ethnicity) may have different slopes. I'm not sure how to compare all the slopes as opposed to single points like Alice 5, Barney 7.

Comment: I am intrigued that your simple model "works fairly well for about 75% of students". This seems to imply that you already know the outcomes for the 100 students.  Do you just want a model that will work better for those 100 students, or do you want to make predictions for a larger population (or perhaps for the same 100 students in a later period)?